# How far can #12 wire be run without voltage drop becoming a problem?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I want to run some 12/2 wire nm-b to my shed in some conduit about 25ft long to some 20a receptacles with a 20a light switch, I know about the switch being 20a but I like it to meet the wire specifications

My question comes down to, how long can I run 12/2 wire without it losing current through distance. I'm running a medium 28 gallon compressor and a table saw, miter saw, etc., not all at the same time but you know what I'm thinking.

Comment: Circuits like yours are routinely run 100 feet or more through mid-size homes. Obviously the concern is a bit greater with high-current tools, but garages are often that far away as well. It's not a problem.

Answer (score 4):

25 feet is no big deal for voltage drop.  We start worrying about 70-100'.

You don't need a 20A switch unless you're switching 20A of lights.  For a common household light, a regular switch will do.

You're speaking precisely about wire type, i.e. NM-B, but that's absolutely the wrong wire for that job.  NM-B can't go outside.   I say "wire" instead of "cable" because you are better off using actual wires in conduit, which is to say THWN-2.  If you want to staple cable to walls at the ends of the conduit run, have the conduit end in a junction box, then use the junction box to splice between your NM (outside conduit) and THWN-2 (in conduit).

You can get multiconductor cable similar to NM that is rated for outside, but it's more expensive than THWN and it will be *much* harder to cram down a conduit.

Make sure you bury deep enough, 6" for rigid conduit, 18" for other conduit.